# Raspberry Pi Refuse to Set GPIO Value

Tags: gpio

I'm trying to use a 5V relay with my Raspberry Pi B (lastest revision) and my Pi refuses to set the value to 1 for the pin connected to my relay. [I'm following this tutorial](http://www.susa.net/wordpress/2012/06/raspberry-pi-relay-using-gpio/)

Steps to reproduce:

`$ echo 4 >/sys/class/gpio/export
$ cd /sys/class/gpio/gpio4
$ echo out >direction
$ echo 1 >value
$ cat value
0`

Comment: Assuming no error messages were given when you entered those commands.  Something must be pulling gpio4 low.  I'd remove it (the relay?) and confirm you understand the hardware.

Comment: Yeah, no error messages are given. When I remove the relay, it does in fact work. I've created the [circuit from this diagram.](http://www.susa.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Relay-Sample.png) Hmm, I agree that it's probably an issue with the circuit (or my job recreating it).

Comment: Perhaps the circuit uses a PNP transistor and you've used an NPN?

Comment: Please post this as an answer and then marked as solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the circuit uses a NPN transistor and I was using a PNP transistor. The PNP transistor was pulling the relay LOW and preventing the Raspberry Pi from setting the value to HIGH (1).

edit:

It may have been a misconnection in the wiring. The transistor was definitely switched, but a bad connection may have been fixed in the process.

Comment: No, a PNP transistor would not explain this unless you also misidentified the base and had an insufficient base resistor.  With a properly chosen resistor, no transistor misconnection or mis selection could force the GPIO to read low.

Comment: Hmm, I only recall switching the transistor. It's possible that a misconnection was fixed in the process. I don't have concrete evidence at the moment to support either claim, so I'll update my answer with that information.

Comment: Still, this cannot happen unless your base resistor is too small.